# why Mathematics meta doesn't allow me to ask this question?

Tags: support, allowed-questions, asking-questions, quality-filter

prove that , if x is rational number then , tan(x) is not rational number.

i tried to ask this question , it says , " ops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

•It does not meet our quality standards.
"
what is their quality standards ?? and why  is this question not allowed to be asked ?

Comment: (1) Were you trying to ask this question here on meta.math.SE (where it does not belong), or on the main site [math.SE](http://mathematics.stackexchange.com) (where it would belong)?  (2) [Similar questions on quality standards](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5104/8348) have been asked before, and given [better answers on StackOverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92075).

Comment: @ArthurFischer , i asked in http://mathematics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: 0 is a rational number...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably just have to make the question a bit longer.

It's not clear what the "quality" standards are but they are automatic.

So just add a few extra words about the question and it will allow it.

Comment: Also, please note that we like to see some work that you have done.  Additionally, some people find the imperative form to be rude (e.g. "Prove ..." or "Solve ...")--make sure your phrase your post as a question.  Capitalization is helpful, too.